# Design pattern for DTO

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-transfer-objects

I have a web application using jdbc for database calls.
I have a service, dto and dao layer.
I have a request xml which is huge. Can I pass the request object to dao method or should I transfer the request to a dto model and then pass the dto object as a paramter to my dao method?
Which is the right approach??

```
public TestServiceClass addSurveySubmitDetails(TestRequestXML testRequestXML){
          //call to dao method
          TestDao = testdao = new TestDao(testRequestXML);

   }

         OR

    public TestServiceClass addSurveySubmitDetails(TestRequestXML testRequestXML){

         //create dto object
         TestDTO testDTO = new TestDTO();
         testDTO .setId(testRequestXML);

          //call to dao method
          TestDao = testdao = new TestDao(testDTO );

   }
```

Which is the right approach??

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your architecture, but as **DTO** is `Data Transfer Object` there's no reason to use them between service and dao layers.

You can have one for service layer I suppose like in code sample below, but anyway it depends on your application's architecture.

```
   public TestServiceClass addSurveySubmitDetails(TestDTO testDTO){
          TestRequestXML testRequestXML = testDTO.getId();
          TestDao = testdao = new TestDao(testRequestXML);

   }
```

More on DTO's

[Data Transfer Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)

[LocalDTO](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/LocalDTO.html)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a right or wrong answer. It's pretty subjective in my opinion.

But I personally like to have a thin layer between the controllers and the services (assuming you're using the MVC pattern), that its only task is to convert requests (XML, Json, etc) to domain objects.

It is quite useful when you have complex domain objects or aggregates of which you need to show information in a view.

Answer (score 0):

YAGNI is good idea, keep it simple design, where possible

Comment: good point but link to an explanation of the acronym would be even better (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

DTOs are really intended for remote calls. If you're sending data over the network to a different virtual machine, use a DTO. If you're sending data to another local class on the same virtual machine, don't bother with a DTO. A DTO is just an efficient way to transfer data remotely. It doesn't really have any advantages anywhere else.